# command 'find' isn't working

Tags: command-line, scripts

```
find /media/shamsad/1E8A00A88A007E91/ -name '*.json' \
    -exec  mongoimport --db twitter --collection twitterCol --file {} \;
```

The above script was working perfectly but the below one is generating an error:

```
find /Desktop/L3T1/DatabaseSessional/TestMongotweet/ -name '*.json' \
    -exec  mongoimport --db twittersmall --collection twitterdata --drop --file {} \;
```

Error:

```
find: ‘/Desktop/L3T1/DatabaseSessional/TestMongotweet/’: No such file or directory
```

Is there a whitespace problem?

Comment: Did you really mean `/Desktop`? or should that be `~/Desktop`?

Comment: It's in my Desktop. So I need to put a '~' sign before Desktop?

Comment: @sphoenix Yes you need to add `~`. Some additional details about it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/516702/is-the-tilde-considered-to-be-a-relative-path

Comment: But why it's working for the first one?

Comment: /media is in the root directory. (assuming that your user name is "bob") your desktop directory will probably  be /home/bob/Desktop... , The "~" is a shortcut for /home/bob

Comment: @NickSillito You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @NickSillito please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Desktop` directory is stored in your home directory, and your home directory is normally a subdirectory of /home with the same name as your login. So if your user name was "bob" your desktop directory will probably be `/home/bob/Desktop` (note that when the account is created, /home/*user_name* is just the default -- it could be set to something else). You can use `~` as a shortcut for typing the path to your home directory.

Therefore if you want to search you Desktop directory, you should refer to it as  `~/Desktop` and your command would become

```
find ~/Desktop/L3T1/DatabaseSessional/TestMongotweet/ -name '*.json' \
-exec  mongoimport --db twittersmall --collection twitterdata --drop --file {} \;
```

`/media`, the place the system typically mounts CDROMs, USB sticks etc., is in the root directory and therefore your first command worked fine.