# Where do I find the zsh manual in Ubuntu versions later than 12.04?

Tags: 14.04, documentation, manpage, zsh

At the moment I am learning `zsh` based on recommendations from friends and colleagues. To my surprise I was unable to find the `man` page for `zsh` and a `man` page named `zshmisc` which apparently was included in earlier versions of the `zsh` package on Ubuntu (e.g. [`zshmisc` for Precise Pangolin](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/zshmisc.1.html)).

Where can I find the documentation for `zsh` *on* my system after installing `zsh`?

Packages `zsh-doc` and `zsh-lovers` are installed. But only the latter even provides a `man` page.

NB: I hope to evade the ugly and hard-to-use concoction that the `info` system is (I don't even have it installed, nor did `zsh-doc` require it) - so `man` pages are preferred in an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [zsh man page documentation missing in packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/399444/zsh-man-page-documentation-missing-in-packages)

Comment: The zsh manpages have been missing for some time in the Ubuntu packages. On Ubuntu 14.04 the manpages are again insalled with the *zsh-common* package (at least since package version 5.0.5-4ubuntu1), which is a dependency of the *zsh* package. (14.04 is also the only version newer than 12.04 that is still supported, by Canonical and this site)

Comment: The latest package on 14.04 is `5.0.2-3ubuntu6`, though. And that doesn't contain the `man` pages.

Comment: You can get `5.0.5-4ubuntu1` from *trusty-backports*.