# Where can I find zsh man pages?

Tags: zsh

I installed the packages `zsh` and `zsh-doc`, but when I type `man zsh`, I get `no manual entry for zsh.` Where can I find zsh docs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [zsh man page documentation missing in packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/399444/zsh-man-page-documentation-missing-in-packages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the docs in `/usr/share/doc/zsh-common`. I suspect if you also install zsh-common, you will also find the `man` pages.

```
ZSH(1)                      General Commands Manual                     ZSH(1)

NAME
       zsh - the Z shell

OVERVIEW
       Because  zsh contains many features, the zsh manual has been split into
       a number of sections:

       zsh          Zsh overview (this section)
       zshroadmap   Informal introduction to the manual
       zshmisc      Anything not fitting into the other sections
<snip>
```

It appears to be a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zsh/+bug/1242108 Posts #21 and 22 suggest work-arounds. It is apparently fixed for Ubuntu 14.10 as it works perfectly on my system.

Comment: I apparently already have zsh-common installed, but it still says `No manual entry`. Is there another package I should install?

Comment: Not that I know of. I tested by installing the three packages and the man page came right up. You might try to sudo apt-get reinstall all three and see if it is corrected.

Comment: There's no such thing as `sudo apt-get reinstall`, apparently. Running `sudo apt-get remove zsh zsh-common zsh-doc && sudo apt-get install zsh zsh-common zsh-doc` doesn't give me man pages, but it does give a warning: `update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/rzsh.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/zsh.1.gz (of link group rzsh) doesn't exist`. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Probably. Please see my edit above.

Comment: Great, running `wget -qO- "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/zsh/zsh/5.0.2/zsh-5.0.2.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fzsh%2Ffiles%2Fzsh%2F5.0.2%2F&ts=1407408881&use_mirror=superb-dca3" | sudo tar xvz -C /usr/share/man/man1/ --wildcards "zsh-5.0.2/Doc/*.1" --strip-components=2 && sudo chown root:root /usr/share/man/man1/zsh*.1` from the comment in that bug report fixed it.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.